# No internet on virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

So I have 3 virtual machines and I copied 1 from a friend of mine. His Virtual Machine does have internet and the other 2 virtual machines I got, also have internet. Now what am I doing wrong at the copied virtual machine? I didn't change anything in my virtual machine

Comment: What is your virtualization software ? Windows Virtual PC ?

Comment: VMWare Workstation

Comment: what problem specifically are you seeing? Can your VM's communicate with the host and each other or is there 0 network activity?

Comment: @txtechhelp 0 network activity in the VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMWare is different from VBox WRT copying VM's; chances are the NIC you have assigned in the VM still has the old MAC address of the NIC being used from your friends PC, so when the VM launches it can't find the NIC with the specified MAC and thus no internet. To fix this, just remove and readd the NIC's for each VM in the settings.

Comment: Nope the network was still on Bridged(automatic) I changed it to NAT and it worked.

Comment: When you switched it to NAT, VMWare detected the correct NIC and changed the associated MAC, essentially the same thing as removing and re adding, but quicker ;) glad it's fixed for you